# How to do an average of values in a pandas table

Tags: pandas, selenium, average, mean

This is the code I have that creates a functioning table of values.

```
items = results.findAll("li")
rows=[]
for item in items: 
    titleElement = item.find("h3")
    priceElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "POSITIVE"})

    if titleElement and priceElement and dateElement:
            data = [dateElement.text, titleElement.text, priceElement.text]
            rows.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=["Purchase Date", "Title", "Price"])
df
```

I am now looking to do an average of the priceElement values

The only way I am familiar with this is through

```
average = sum/len
```

But when I do

```
if priceElement:
    average = sum(priceElement)/len(priceElement)

print(average.text)
```

I get the error "average is not defined". How do I develop this code?

Comment: `df['Price'].mean()` ? You might also need to convert to a numeric type first since it appears you're adding the values as text to the DataFrame. A sample DataFrame as well as expected output would improve the ability to answer this question significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Price` column first to numeric and get its `mean` to get the average value.

```py
average = pd.to_numeric(df["Price"]).mean()    #If Price is number in string
```

Or if price is already numeric then you can do the following.

```py
average = df["Price"].mean()    #If Price is integer or float
```